# How to prove with contradiction that if $n^{5}$ is odd, then is also $n$ odd?

Tags: number-theory

$n\in \mathbb{N}$

Because it should be done with contradiction, should we begin with assumption that $n$ is some even number, $n=2k$ ?

If so, then how should we continue our proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\;n=2k\;$ , i.e. it is even, then:

$$n^5=(2k)^5=2^5k^5=32k^5\;\leftarrow\;\text{this is even! Contradiction}$$

Comment: I understand that part, but after proving that $n^{5}$  is even for even $n$, is that enough of a proof for my first statement that if $n^{5}$ is odd than &n& is also odd?

Comment: @TarsNolan Yes, since $$\left(n\;\text{even}\implies n^5\;\text{even}\right)\equiv \left(n^5\text{not even=odd}\implies n\;\text{not even=odd}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, $(2k)^5=32k^5$ seems *very* even... :)

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is even then $n = 2m$ and $n^5=(2m)^5 = 2 \left( 2^4m^5 \right) = 2k$, with $k = 16m^5$.